# Doubt : About Dual Boot(in partition)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 14.04, windows-7

I have a computer on which all the hard disks are partitioned and are already used by me. Since the newer versions of Ubuntu require a partiton for dualbooting I was thinking of getting another extra hard disk and installing Ubuntu on that particular disk.  Does this seem like the correct thing to do or am I making a mistake somewhere? I would like to know the safest way to do it without affecting anything. Some advice would be helpful since I see a lot of threads where people try to install Ubuntu and the UBuntu boots but the original OS does not.

Answer (score 0):

I run a dual-boot, but with lower systems: Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows XP.

You don't need another partition for installing Ubuntu. The technical guy who installed Ubuntu on my computer told me almost all Linux distributions make their own little space on your computer. That space is inaccessible through any other OS.

In other words, you can install Ubuntu along with your Windows 7 (by choosing the option Install With Windows or something). Ubuntu will automatically make some space and install in that.

I had four drives (partitions). They all work as they should. There's even the entire C drive in which all my Windows software and even Windows XP itself is installed. There's no problem in accessing.

Answer (score 0):

Safest way is to install on a new partition, or hdd entirely.